# PostgreSQL Upsert Using Records

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I am currently trying to perform an upsert (using 3.10-snapshot) using records and have noticed that the update's `set` data isn't being added to the query when I use `addRecord(R)`.  In the DAO I have:

```java
    try (Connection writeConn = DatabaseManager.getConnection(true);
            final DSLContext writeContext = DatabaseManager.getBuilder(writeConn);
            InsertQuery<UserProgramAssignmentsRecord> programAssignmentsUpdateQuery = writeContext
                    .insertQuery(AccessControlWriteDAO.userProgramAssignments)) {
        programAssignmentsUpdateQuery.onDuplicateKeyUpdate(true);

        programAssignments.forEach(pa -> programAssignmentsUpdateQuery.addRecord(pa.toRecord()));

        if (!programAssignments.isEmpty()) {
            if (AccessControlWriteDAO.logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
                AccessControlWriteDAO.logger.info(writeContext.renderInlined(programAssignmentsUpdateQuery));
            }
            // programAssignmentsUpdateQuery.execute();
        }
    } catch (final SQLException e) {
        throw new DAOException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
```

Inside of the class for programAssignments, I have:

```
/**
 * <p>
 * This method turns the object into a {@link Record} that can then be attached to a {@link Connection} and
 * {@link DSLContext}.
 * </p>
 * 
 * @return A usable {@link UserProgramAssignmentsRecord}
 */
public UserProgramAssignmentsRecord toRecord() {
    UserProgramAssignmentsRecord upar = new UserProgramAssignmentsRecord();
    getAdministerProgram().ifPresent(upar::setAdminister);
    getCreateProjects().ifPresent(upar::setCreateProjects);
    getJustification().ifPresent(upar::setJustification);
    getProgramId().ifPresent(upar::setProgramId);
    getUserId().ifPresent(upar::setUserId);
    getViewRevisions().ifPresent(upar::setViewRevisions);

    return upar;
}
```

The code produces the following query:

```sql
insert into "%%removed%%"."user_project_assignments" (
    "project_id", 
    "edit_draft", 
    "justification", 
    "user_id"
)
values (
    98332, 
    true, 
    'The user created the project', 
    675
)
on conflict (
    "project_id", 
    "user_id"
) do update
set [ no fields are updated ]
```

Do I have to switch to using `addValue(Field<T>,T)`, `addValueForUpdateField(Field<T>,T)`, and newRecord?  I would have *thought* that passing records would be equivalent, but that doesn't seem to be the case as `addRecord(R)` doesn't seem to be setting the fields to update -or- am I doing something wrong in my `toRecord()` method?  Is there some kind of `addRecordForUpdate(R)` for `InsertQuery` objects?  And how well does this work for multi-row upserts (which is what I'm trying to do)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing documentation, I think this is a bit of a... deficiency....  While one might *think* that `addRecord(R)` + `onDuplicateKeyUpdate(true)` would mean that the update data is set *or* that there would be an `addValueForUpdate(R)`, that would (clearly) be wrong.  My solution was to have my POJOs also have another method `toExcludedMap()` that looked like this:

```
/**
 * <p>
 * This method returns mappings that can be used in an UPSERT in the update portion of the query.
 * </p>
 *
 * @return A map between the assignments table and the excluded table
 */
public Map<Field<?>, Field<?>> toExcludedMap() {
    final UserProgramAssignments excludedTable = UserProgramAssignment.pua.as("excluded");

    final Map<Field<?>, Field<?>> excludedMap = new HashMap<>(4);
    getAdministerProgram()
            .ifPresent(i -> excludedMap.put(UserProgramAssignment.pua.ADMINISTER, excludedTable.ADMINISTER));
    getCreateProjects().ifPresent(
            i -> excludedMap.put(UserProgramAssignment.pua.CREATE_PROJECTS, excludedTable.CREATE_PROJECTS));
    getJustification()
            .ifPresent(i -> excludedMap.put(UserProgramAssignment.pua.JUSTIFICATION, excludedTable.JUSTIFICATION));
    getViewRevisions().ifPresent(
            i -> excludedMap.put(UserProgramAssignment.pua.VIEW_REVISIONS, excludedTable.VIEW_REVISIONS));

    return excludedMap;
}
```

I then adjusted my DAO to do like this:

```
    try (Connection writeConn = DatabaseManager.getConnection(true);
            final DSLContext writeContext = DatabaseManager.getBuilder(writeConn);
            InsertQuery<UserProgramAssignmentsRecord> programAssignmentsUpdateQuery = writeContext
                    .insertQuery(AccessControlWriteDAO.userProgramAssignments)) {
        programAssignmentsUpdateQuery.onDuplicateKeyUpdate(true);

        programAssignments
                .forEach(assignment -> AccessControlWriteDAO.addRecordToUpsert(programAssignmentsUpdateQuery,
                        assignment.toRecord(), assignment.toExcludedMap()));

        if (!programAssignments.isEmpty()) {
            if (AccessControlWriteDAO.logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
                AccessControlWriteDAO.logger.info(writeContext.renderInlined(programAssignmentsUpdateQuery));
            }
            programAssignmentsUpdateQuery.execute();
        }
    } catch (final SQLException e) {
        throw new DAOException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
```

I then, to keep things clean, made a new method that updates the InsertQuery:

```
/**
 * <p>
 * This method is used to add a record and the update information to an UPSERT query.
 * </p>
 *
 * @param query
 *            The query to add to
 * @param record
 *            The record to add
 * @param excludedMap
 *            The mappings to the "excluded" table for this record
 */
private static <R extends Record> void addRecordToUpsert(final InsertQuery<R> query, final R record,
        final Map<Field<?>, Field<?>> excludedMap) {
    query.addRecord(record);
    query.addValuesForUpdate(excludedMap);
}
```

It *kind of* sucks that we don't have symmetry and that I 1) have to make a map, 2) have to make yet another method call to get the data in *but* I believe that this is the only way currently.  It would be nice if jOOQ added the update data or at least took in a record and excluded the PK (since if we're updating on duplicate keys, clearly the PK hasn't changed), but maybe this isn't possible.